# ZeroMQ: very high latency with PUSH/PULL

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

## Summary

I see very high latency at the receiver using `zmq.PUSH/PULL` sockets.

### Details

I'm new to ZeroMQ, and am trying to send a few MBytes from the sender to the receiver (my final aim is to send a camera stream from the sender to the receiver). The sender and receiver are different machines on the same local network (one is a Mac and the other is running Ubuntu 18.04, if that matters). The sender is able to send its packets very fast (I'm guessing they get buffered in some zmq/tcp queue), but the receiver receives them very slowly with increasing latency per packet.

Here's the sender :

```
  1 """
  2 Sender
  3 """
  4 import zmq
  5 from time import time
  6 import sys
  7 
  8 addr = "tcp://192.168.86.33:5555"
  9 
 10 context = zmq.Context()
 11 socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
 12 socket.bind(addr)
 13 
 14 num = 0
 15 while True:
 16     frame = [0] * 1000000
 17     ts = time()
 18     num += 1
 19     socket.send_pyobj(dict(num=num, frame=frame, ts=ts))
 20 
 21     delay = time() - ts
 22     print("Sender:: pkt_num: {}, delay: {}".format(num, delay))
```

And the receiver :

```
  1 """                                                                              
  2 Receiver                                                                         
  3 """                                                                              
  4 import zmq                                                                       
  5 from time import time                                                            
  6                                                                                  
  7 addr = "tcp://192.168.86.33:5555"                                                
  8 context = zmq.Context()                                                          
  9                                                                                  
 10 socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)                                                
 11 socket.connect(addr)                                                             
 12                                                                                  
 13 while True:                                                                      
 14     msg = socket.recv_pyobj()                                                    
 15     frame = msg['frame']                                                         
 16     num = msg['num']                                                             
 17     ts = msg['ts']                                                               
 18                                                                                  
 19     delay = time() - ts                                                          
 20                                                                                  
 21     if True:                                                                     
 22         print("Receiver:: pkt_num: {} latency: {}".format(num, delay))
```

When I run this, I see the sender is able to send its packets very quickly :

```
Sender:: pkt_num: 1, delay: 0.026965618133544922
Sender:: pkt_num: 2, delay: 0.018309354782104492
Sender:: pkt_num: 3, delay: 0.01821303367614746
Sender:: pkt_num: 4, delay: 0.016669273376464844
Sender:: pkt_num: 5, delay: 0.01674652099609375
Sender:: pkt_num: 6, delay: 0.01668095588684082
Sender:: pkt_num: 7, delay: 0.015082836151123047
Sender:: pkt_num: 8, delay: 0.014363527297973633
Sender:: pkt_num: 9, delay: 0.014063835144042969
Sender:: pkt_num: 10, delay: 0.014398813247680664
```

But the receiver sees very high and growing packet latencies :

```
Receiver:: pkt_num: 1 latency: 0.1272585391998291
Receiver:: pkt_num: 2 latency: 0.2539491653442383
Receiver:: pkt_num: 3 latency: 0.40800905227661133
Receiver:: pkt_num: 4 latency: 0.5737316608428955
Receiver:: pkt_num: 5 latency: 0.7272651195526123
Receiver:: pkt_num: 6 latency: 0.9418754577636719
Receiver:: pkt_num: 7 latency: 1.0799565315246582
Receiver:: pkt_num: 8 latency: 1.228663682937622
Receiver:: pkt_num: 9 latency: 1.3731486797332764
Receiver:: pkt_num: 10 latency: 1.5067603588104248
```

I tried swapping the sender and receiver between the Mac and Linux machines, and saw the same behavior. Since my goal is to send a video stream from the sender to the receiver, these high latencies make this unusable for that purpose.

---

## Edit 1

Based on `user3666197`'s suggestion, I edited the sender/receiver test code to remove some overheads. On the sender side keep sending the same dict. I also added more prints.

Sender:

```
 14 num = 0
 15 frame = [0] * 1000000
 16 payload = dict(num=0, frame=frame, ts=0.0)
 17 while True:
 18     payload['num'] += 1
 19     payload['ts'] = time()
 20     socket.send_pyobj(payload)
 21 
 22     delay = time() - payload['ts']
 23     print("Sender:: pkt_num: {:>6d}, delay: {:6f}" \
 24           .format(payload['num'], delay))
```

Receiver

```
 10 socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
 11 socket.connect(addr)
 12 clk = zmq.Stopwatch()
 13 clk.start()
 14 
 15 while True:
 16     iterT = clk.stop()
 17     clk.start()
 18     msg = socket.recv_pyobj()
 19     rcvT = clk.stop()
 20     delay = time() - msg['ts']
 21 
 22     print("Server:: pkt_num: {:>6d} latency: {:>6f} iterT: {} rcvT: {}" \
 23          .format(msg['num'], delay, iterT, rcvT))
 24     clk.start()
```

The sender's per packet delay has reduced further. An interesting datapoint revealed is that the receiver takes almost 0.15s to receive each packet, which seems to be the main problem.

```
Sender:: pkt_num:      1, delay: 1.797830
Sender:: pkt_num:      2, delay: 0.025297
Sender:: pkt_num:      3, delay: 0.019500
Sender:: pkt_num:      4, delay: 0.019500
Sender:: pkt_num:      5, delay: 0.018166
Sender:: pkt_num:      6, delay: 0.017320
Sender:: pkt_num:      7, delay: 0.017258
Sender:: pkt_num:      8, delay: 0.017277
Sender:: pkt_num:      9, delay: 0.017426
Sender:: pkt_num:     10, delay: 0.017340
```

In the receiver's prints, rcvT is the per-packet receive time in microseconds.

```
Server:: pkt_num:      1 latency: 2.395570 iterT: 1 rcvT: 331601
Server:: pkt_num:      2 latency: 0.735229 iterT: 1 rcvT: 137547
Server:: pkt_num:      3 latency: 0.844345 iterT: 1 rcvT: 134385
Server:: pkt_num:      4 latency: 0.991852 iterT: 1 rcvT: 166980
Server:: pkt_num:      5 latency: 1.089429 iterT: 2 rcvT: 117047
Server:: pkt_num:      6 latency: 1.190770 iterT: 2 rcvT: 119466
Server:: pkt_num:      7 latency: 1.348077 iterT: 2 rcvT: 174566
Server:: pkt_num:      8 latency: 1.460732 iterT: 1 rcvT: 129858
Server:: pkt_num:      9 latency: 1.585445 iterT: 2 rcvT: 141948
Server:: pkt_num:     10 latency: 1.717757 iterT: 1 rcvT: 149666
```

---

## Edit 2

I implemented the solution pointed out in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87815/120509) that uses PUB/SUB, and it works perfectly; I get 30fps video on the receiver. I still do not understand why my PUSH/PULL sample sees a delay.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *"ZeroMQ: very high latency with `PUSH/PULL`"*

The ZeroMQ `PUSH/PULL` archetype is a part of the story. Let's decompose the claimed latency :

**1 )**
Let's measure the actual payload assembly costs `[us]` :

```
aClk = zmq.Stopwatch()
num  = 0    
while True:
    aClk.start() #--------------------------------------- .start() the microsecond timer
    frame     = [0] * 1000000
    ts        = time()
    num      += 1
    aPayLOAD  = dict( num   = num,
                      frame = frame,
                      ts    = ts
                      )
    _1 = aClk.stop() #---------------------------------- .stop() the microsecond timer
    aPayLOAD['ts'] = time()

    aClk.start() #-------------------------------------- .start() the microsecond timer
    socket.send_pyobj( aPayLOAD )
    _2 = aClk.stop() #---------------------------------- .stop() the microsecond timer
    delay        = time() - aPayLOAD['ts']

    print( "Sender:: pkt_num: {0:>6d}, assy: {1:>6d} [us] .send_pyobj(): {2:>6d} [us] 'delay': {3:>10.6f} [s] ".format( num, _1, _2, delay ) )
```

**2 )**
Doing the same for the receiving side, you have a clear picture of how many `[us]` got consumed on the Python side, before the ZeroMQ has ever touched the first byte of the payload.

**3 )**
Next comes the performance tuning :

- Avoid Python garbage collection
- Improve the wasted memory-management ( avoid creating new instances, better inject data into memory-efficient "handlers" ( **`numpy.ndarray.data`**-zones instead of assigning re-composing **`list`**-s into a python variable )
- refactor the code to avoid expensive **`dict`**-based key-value mapping and rather use compact binary maps, as available in **`struct`**-module ( your proposed mapping is both static & trivial )
- test adding a compression-step ( may improve a bit the over-the-network hop latency )

**4 )**
Only now the ZeroMQ part comes :

- may test improved performance envelopes from adding more IO-threads into either of **`Context( nIO_threads )`**-instances
- may go in for **`.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE, 1 )`** to ignore all non-"last" frames, as video-streaming may get no added value from "late" re-creation of already "old" frames

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I've edited my test cases with your suggestions, see "Edit 1" above. I see that the sender takes about 0.015s to send each message, but the receiver takes 10x that to receive each message.

Comment: You mix apples with oranges. ZeroMQ .send()-method just puts the content payload into the Context()-instance's internal engine, so the times do not represent anything but that marshaled ownership of the payload, before any actual processing takes place. Retrieving a PULL-side arrived message from the internal Context()-instance's managed outgoing queue than computes the E2E-latency, yet you see no details where and why it got accumulated. So performance tuning needs more insight into this ( at least hope your hosts had well sync-ed ~order of magnitude under the [us]-timer's localhost clocks )

Comment: Ah I see, so the send is asynchronous, so the send delay doesn't mean much here. `pyobj_recv` takes 0.15s though, that alone would mean I can't receive 30fps video. I also increased `io_threads` but that didn't change the e2e latency. Also if I insert a `sleep(1)` in the loop on the sender, it reduces the e2e latency a lot, implying there is significant delay on the sender side as well. I'll update the question with that data as well.